# Rebus Databus with multiple attachments

Tags: rebus

When using Rebus' databus, [found here](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Data-bus), is there any way I can add multiple databus attachments? Assuming I have two different sources, which I want to publish.

What I'm currently trying:

```
private async void AddTwoDataBusAttachments(Stream firstSource, Stream secondSource, Message message)
    {
        using (firstSource)
        {
            var dataBusFirstAttachment = await _bus.Advanced
                .DataBus
                .CreateAttachment(source: firstSource)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var dataBusSecondAttachment = await _bus.Advanced
                .DataBus
                .CreateAttachment(source: secondSource)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            await _bus.Publish(eventMessage: new NewMessage
                {
                    DocumentIdentifier = message.DocumentIdentifier,
                    FirstAttachmentIdentifier = dataBusFirstAttachment.Id,
                    SecondAttachmentIdentifier = dataBusSecondAttachment.Id
                })
                .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
    }
```

But I get an error when it comes to creating `dataBusSecondAttachment`: `Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: 'Could not save data with ID 0e9125a8-4c3a-4dec-8223-6925b8ae4d40'`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that prevents you from creating multiple attachments, so I suspect your error is caused by something else. Could you update the question and post the full stack trace?

Comment: Alright, like you said, the problem seemed to stem from something else. The source that provoked the error seemed to have been disposed at the time of attachment creation. I changed up the method calling `AddTwoDataBusAttachments` and it works now.